# How to use data-prototype using table & tr tags instead of Div in symfony

Tags: jquery, html, symfony

I'm trying to data-prototype option for adding table rows. But the default code snippet provided by symfony is using the  tags as a result the newly appended elements are using

tags which makes the fields to come one after one instead of one adjacent to another which looks like a form. All I want a table and tr rows structure when I click add row an  should be append but the div and li tags are appended automatically

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var list = jQuery('#fields-list');

    // grab the prototype template
    var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');

    newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, count);
    count++;

    // create a new list element and add it to the list
    var newLi = jQuery('<tr></tr>').html(newWidget);

    newLi.appendTo(list);
  });
})
```